# SAS - How to keep the earliest date considering a missing

Tags: sas

A need to create a new variable to repeat the earliest date for a ID visit and if it missing it should type missing, after a missing it should keep the earliest  date since it was missing(like in the example). I've tried the LAG function and it didn't work; I also try the keep function but just repeat the 25NOV2015 for all records. The final result/"what I need" is in the last column.

Thanks

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGdAo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `retain` statement. Retain means your value in each observation won't be reinitialized to a missing. So in the next iteration of data step your variable remembers its value.

**Sample data**

```
data a;
    input date;
    format date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
.
5
6
7
.
1
2
.
9
;
run;
```

**Solution**

```
data b;
    set a;

    retain new_date;
    format new_date ddmmyy10.;

    if date = . then
        new_date = .;

    if new_date = . then
        new_date = date;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robert. But, If I try with more than one ID? I tried to put: data b;
    set a;
 BY ID;

Comment: What I did was: data b;
    set a; By ID;

    retain new_date;
    format new_date ddmmyy10.;

    if date = . then
        new_date = .;

    if new_date = . then
        new_date = date;
run;

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any data I will make up some. Also since the fact that your variable is a date doesn't really impact the answer I will just use some integers as they are easier to type.

```
data have ;
  input id value @@ ;
cards;
1 . 1 2 1 3 1 . 1 5 1 6 1 . 1 8
2 1 2 2 2 3 2 . 2 5 2 6
;;;;
```

Basically your algorithm says that you want to store the value when either the current value is missing or stored value is missing.  With multiple BY groups you would also want to set it when you start a new group.

```
data want ;
 set have ;
 by id ;
 retain new_value ;
 if first.id or missing(new_value) or missing(value)
  then new_value=value;
run;
```

Results:

```
                       new_
Obs    id    value    value

  1     1      .        .
  2     1      2        2
  3     1      3        2
  4     1      .        .
  5     1      5        5
  6     1      6        5
  7     1      .        .
  8     1      8        8
  9     2      1        1
 10     2      2        1
 11     2      3        1
 12     2      .        .
 13     2      5        5
 14     2      6        5
```

Comment: Tom, thank you so much, so important for me to have a solution. I'm new here, sorry I didn't post any data, i'm quite lost. Thank you again! It works!